# How to send list of string values as "LIST" object in Dozer (custom-converter-param)?

Tags: dozer

Currently the list is passed in the custom-converter-param as "aa,bb,cc,dd" etc., but the parameter is passed as string and we need to again split the string with comma and finally save it as a list for processing.

Is there is a way to pass the list of string object as "List" as a parameter?

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 0):

In every custom converter the value of the property **custom-converter-param** is passed to the field *`parameter`* of type *`String`* in  `org.dozer.DozerConverter<A, B>` class, and its only getter method contract is like this:

> public String getParameter()

So No, is not possible to retrieve the value as a List. The simplest/best thing to do here is to create a method *getParameterAsList* in your own converter to split the String value.